# Systemctl service not executed on boot

Tags: systemctl

I created a short script to set an interface to down,

```
[Unit]
Description=Down

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/base -c 'ifconfig eth0 down'
```

I have done systemctl enable, and systemctl start works as expected to set the interface to down.
However, on rebooting it is not executed after logging in. Is there anything I missed?

The above is done on a RPi4 with the 64-bit version of Raspberian OS.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps be missing the [Install] property?

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```